# How can I detect whether the alt/option key is down in GTK on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, gtk, pygtk, alt-key

I want to detect whether the alt/option key is pressed during a mouse drag in GTK on Mac OS X.  I am using pygtk.  Normally, holding down alt would add MOD1_MASK to event.state, but alt does affect event.state at all.  In key press events alt shows up as gtk.keysyms.kana_switch, but this is not sufficient for my purposes since the user might press alt in a different application and switch to mine by clicking.

Is there an available setting that would cause alt/option to show up as a modifier in event.state?  Alternatively, is there a way of detecting whether a key is currently down even if the key down event went to a different application?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `gtk.accelerator_get_default_mod_mask()`
http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/unstable/checklist-modifiers.html